# Angular get value in URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

If I wanted to get a specific value from the URL within Angular I'm looking at how to parse this data.

Example:

```
 http://localhost:1337/doc-home/#/tips/5?paginatePage=1
```

I want to get the "5"

HTML:

```
<a href="#/tips/comments/{{ tip.id }}?groupid={{ ????? }}" class="btn-yellow">Add / View Comments</a>
```

module.js

```
 .when('/tips/comments/:group?id', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/comments.html'
```

controller.js

```
  .controller('TipCommentsCtrl',

     function ($http, $scope, $routeParams, Categories, Tip, $location, error, $sce) {
```

**UPDATE**

I am getting CLOSER thanks to the answers from you all.

I posted another question which should help to explain what my problem is

[Angular routeParams not working URL is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32276886/angular-routeparams-not-working-url-is-changing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your requirements you can choose any of either:

1. If you're using ngRoute, you can inject $routeParams into your controller.ngRoute is a angular core module which is good for basic scenarios.
   URL: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute
   http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

   If you are using the RouteProvider and routeParams: The route wires up the URL to your Controller/View and the routeParams can be passed into the controller. Check out the [Angular seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project. Within the app.js you'll find an example for the route provider. To use params simply append them like this:

   ```
      $routeProvider.when('/view1/:param1/:param2', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html',    
        controller: 'MyCtrl1'
      });
   ```

   Then in your controller inject $routeParams:

   ```
      .controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,     
      $routeParams) {
        var param1 = $routeParams.param1;
        var param1 = $routeParams.param2;
        ...
      }]);
   ```

Also can get other arbitrary params in the query string form /view/1/2?other=12 with $routeParams.other.

2. Ui-router is a contributed module which is overcome the problems of ngRoute. Mainly Nested/Complex views.If you're using angular-ui-router, you can inject $stateParams. URL: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router, https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing.

   For Example : http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

Though your answer is specifically on how to get the parameters here i have added more relevant information on what to choose and how to use. I hope it helps. Thank you.

Comment: See Update with URL to another question

Answer (score 1):

The `$routeParams` service gives you the ability to access the route parameters and returns an object.

In order to get the parameter group in your example `/tips/comments/group?id..` use `$routeParams.group`

Comment: See Update with URL to another question

Answer (score 0):

You will have the details in `$routeParams`

> $routeParams.group

Comment: See Update with URL to another question